# CMIS: Get human-readable name of a user

Tags: cmis

Some [CMIS](http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.1/cs01/CMIS-v1.1-cs01.html) methods return a username, for instance:

Request: `Document -> cmis:lastModifiedBy`
Result: `nraoul42`

Is there any way to get the "pretty name" of the user, using only CMIS?
For instance `Nicolas Raoul` instead of `nraoul42`.

I think 100% of the ECM products store username with both a machine-oriented and a human-oriented form, so that is a feature that CMIS might have implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all ECM products can provide human-readable names. In some scenarios the ECM system only deals with user ids while the rest of the user data is managed in a LDAP system or something similar.

Some ECM systems provide human-readable user names as CMIS extensions, though. But there is no standardized way to retrieve human-readable user names.